# Focusing first combo box using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have combo boxes with same name and ID. I want to focus first combo box.

How can I do this?

```
document.getElementById('test').focus();
```

This is the javascript code I was given to set the focus on the combo box but nothing happens.

I have a combo box like:

```
<select name="test" id="test">
         <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
         <option value="0.50">0.50</option>
          <option value="1.00">1.00</option>
</select>

<select name="test" id="test">
         <option value="t1">t1</option>
         <option value="t2">t2</option>
         <option value="t3">t3</option>
</select>
```

In my page I have the combo boxes like this with same name and ID.

Now I want to set focus to the first combo box .How can I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: An `id` ***must*** be unique within the document. A duplicate `id` is invalid html. Use a class name instead.

Comment: You can use JQuery to select the elements and focus the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have mulitple elements with the same `id`!

try this:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="first" id="first">
     <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
     <option value="0.50">0.50</option>
     <option value="1.00">1.00</option>
</select>

<select name="second" id="second">
     <option value="t1">t1</option>
     <option value="t2">t2</option>
     <option value="t3">t3</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('first').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

move select focus on the top row of function, before call all elements. example

```
function myfunc()
    {
    document.getElementById('myselect').focus();
    document..........
    }
```